# Expected a ':' after a key at 1332 - Selenium JAVA/TestNG

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, testing, testng

I have a project with selenium in java and i use TestNG for the suits to execute regression tests. Im trying to execute one, and doesnt matter wheter i try doing it on Firefox or Chrome that i get an error. The explorer opens with 'data' as url and with empty content, and then immediatly closes to do the same once and once again. I get the following error message:
[image]

The 'Hubo un error al intentar obtener variables' is a custom exception message.

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551) Instead [edit] your question to include the stack trace as properly formatted text. It would also help if you showed the code of the failing test, because as it is, we're just guessing.

Comment: Can you include the causing exception w/ stack?